# I am seeing an error while trying to update Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04

Tags: 20.04, 22.04

I am seeing an error while trying to update Ubuntu 20.04 to 22.04.

Can anyone tell me how to solve this error ?

```
ERROR:
A problem occurred during the update. This is usually some sort of network problem, please check your network connection and retry. 

W:Updating from such a repository can't be done securely, and is therefore disabled by default.,
W:See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.,
W:GPG error: https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable
InRelease: The following signatures couldn't be verified because the public key is not available: NO_PUBKEY A8580BDC82D3DC6C,
E:The repository 'https://brave-browser-apt-release.s3.brave.com stable InRelease' is not signed.
```

Comment: Remove the ppa and all software installed from it before upgrading.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a problem of Ubuntu's it's that you have the Brave software repository in the `/etc/apt/sources.list.d`. Solution is to manually remove the brave-software file in there and rerun the process upgrade, restore brave after you're completed.

You don't have to "remove the software" from the computer, you just have to put that ppa back from the Brave website when you're done. The brave browser works on Jammy just fine. It's mostly an accounting problem within apt itself.

Comment: how do i manually remove brave-software

Comment: `sudo apt remove brave-browser`, but that will not remove the content that is causing the trouble which is a file in /etc/apt/sources.list.d

Comment: i installed successful than you for your help